# Why Can Composer See My Package But Not Find To Install?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I can't figure this out.  I have my package on packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/jafo232/ambientapi

And when I try to install it via composer with

```
composer require jafo232/ambientapi
```

I get:

> > [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package jafo232/ambientapi.
>
> Did you mean this?
>         jafo232/ambientapi

Is this just an internal issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was that I did not add a tag to indicate a staple version:

```
git tag -a 1.00
```

Then:

```
git push --tags
```

You should note there is a delay, even if you manually pull from Packagist.  It can take up to 10 minutes before it shows up.

I hope this helps others.